# Парсинг JSON, получение значения

Tags: android, json, парсер, kotlin, search

Есть json-файл.

```
[
{
"code": 1,
"name": "Карп живой"
},
{
"code": 2,
"name": "Осетр живой"
},
{
"code": 3,
"name": "Сом живой"
},
...
]
```

Открываю его, считываю. Как получить значение из "name" по значению "code". Например, в функцию будет приходить String = 3, нужно получить значение "Сом живой" из данного json'a

Comment: `JSONArray` вам в помощь. Можете [здесь](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) потренироваться.

Comment: Туда куда вам приходит `int x  = 3` (`String = 3` не правильно) проходите в цикле `JSONArray` где берете из каждой ячейки массива объект  `JSONObject` и из этого `JSONObject` берете значение `code`, если к примеру `x==code` то  берете `name`, и будет `name = "Сом живой"` так как `x = 3`, и `code = 3` из этого `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String getName(int code){
    JSONArray rootArray = getJsonFileToArray();
    // вместо length может быть size
    for (int i =0; i < rootArray.length ; i++){
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) rootArray.get(i);
        if (obj.get("code") == code) return obj.get("name")
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Что то на подобие этого